# having issue when placing an outer rectangle covering three small rectangles in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I am trying to draw a large graphical structure where lots of boxes connect to one another. In one of the steps, I go down with an arrow and draw a large rectangle. Inside this large one, I place another three boxes. For some reasons, the large rectangle is not visible. When I perform this operation for a large rectangle with two boxes, it perfectly works.

Here's a small example for illustration.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[boxstyle/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm}]

% Starting box
\node[boxstyle] (box11) {Box 11};

% New Box 12 below Box 11
\node[below=3cm of box11, minimum height=7.5cm, minimum width=3cm, boxstyle] (box12) {};
\node[left=0.2cm of box12] {2020};
\node[draw, rectangle, above=0.5cm of box12.center, yshift=0.3cm, boxstyle] (innerBox5) {Inner 5};
\node[draw, rectangle, boxstyle] at (box12.center) (innerBox6) {Inner 6};
\node[draw, rectangle, below=0.5cm of box12.center, yshift=-0.3cm, boxstyle] (innerBox7) {Inner 7};

% Arrow from Box 11 to Box 12
\draw[->] (box11.south) -- (box12.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite `minimum width` and `minimum height` with the `boxstyle` - order matters.

```
\node[below=3cm of box11, boxstyle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=7.5cm] (box12) {};
```